# SVG to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm getting defeated by some code and I need some help.
I'm aware that you cannot edit external SVG files in JS so the idea
here is to convert SVG code and remake it in JavaScript.

I cannot find any references on how to make this conversion, all I can find is SVG to jsx however I'm writing vanilla JavaScript not using React framework.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="482.026" height="172.554" viewBox="0 0 482.026 172.554">
  <defs>
    <filter id="layerOuter" x="0" y="35.6" width="364.473" height="100.059" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.459"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="layerBase" x="0" y="107.175" width="364.473" height="35.78" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur-2"/>
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.431"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur-2"/>
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g id="frmMenu" transform="translate(-1395.974 -860.8)">
    <g id="btnGroupLayers" transform="translate(0 -9)">
      <g id="LayerBar">
        <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1395.97, 869.8)" filter="url(#layerOuter)">
          <path id="layerOuter-2" data-name="layerOuter" d="M730.735,40.209q-.821-5.562-7.2-5.562H398.941q-6.382,0-7.112,5.562l-.182,1.732v60.177q0,7.294,7.294,7.294h324.59q7.294,0,7.294-7.294V41.941l-.091-1.732M388,102.574V41.941Q388,31,398.941,31h324.59q10.941,0,10.941,10.941v60.633q-.273,10.485-10.941,10.485H398.941q-10.668,0-10.941-10.485" transform="translate(-379 10.6)" fill="#9b9dad"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1395.97, 869.8)" filter="url(#layerBase)">
          <path id="layerBase-2" data-name="layerBase" d="M734.473,70.25v6.838q0,10.941-10.941,10.941H398.941Q388,88.03,388,77.088V70.25q.274,10.485,10.941,10.485h324.59q10.668,0,10.941-10.485" transform="translate(-379 42.92)" fill="#616374"/>
        </g>
        <path id="layerMid" d="M729.088,38.562l.091,1.732v60.177q0,7.294-7.294,7.294H397.294q-7.294,0-7.294-7.294V40.294l.182-1.732Q390.912,33,397.294,33h324.59q6.382,0,7.2,5.562m-3.556,1.732-.091-1.276.091.091q-.638-2.462-3.647-2.462H463.853l-5.106,5.106-5.106-5.106h-17.05l-4.1,4.1-4.1-4.1H397.294q-3.009,0-3.465,2.371l-.091.365-.091.912V83.877l5.015,5.015-5.015,5.015v6.565q0,3.647,3.647,3.647H564.878l5.015-5.015,5.015,5.015H652.5l2.827-2.826,2.826,2.826h63.733q3.647,0,3.647-3.647V58.712l-4.377-4.376,4.377-4.377V40.294" transform="translate(1018.621 882.048)" fill="#727685"/>
        <path id="layerInner" d="M723.885,38.647v9.665l-4.377,4.377,4.377,4.376V98.824q0,3.647-3.647,3.647H656.5l-2.826-2.826-2.826,2.826H573.26l-5.015-5.015-5.015,5.015H395.647q-3.647,0-3.647-3.647V92.259l5.015-5.015L392,82.23V38.647l.091-.912.091-.365Q392.638,35,395.647,35h31.091l4.1,4.1,4.1-4.1h17.05l5.106,5.106L462.206,35H720.237q3.009,0,3.647,2.462l-.091-.091.091,1.276" transform="translate(1020.268 883.694)" fill="#838796"/>
      </g>
      <g id="optionLayer04" transform="translate(213)">
        <path id="optionInt04" d="M812.1,156.3q.25-1.3,1.9-1.3h33a1.8,1.8,0,0,1,2,1.35l-.05-.05.05.7v5.3l-2.4,2.4,2.4,2.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2,2H814a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2-2v-3.6l2.75-2.75L812,180.9V157l.05-.5.05-.2" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d3bf8f"/>
        <path id="optionOuter04" d="M808,190.25V157q0-6,6-6h33q6,0,6,6v33.25q-.15,5.75-6,5.75H814q-5.85,0-6-5.75m2.1-34.2-.1.95v33q0,4,4,4h33q4,0,4-4V157l-.05-.95Q850.5,153,847,153H814q-3.5,0-3.9,3.05" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d9cdaf"/>
        <path id="optionInner04" d="M810.1,156.05q.4-3.05,3.9-3.05h33q3.5,0,3.95,3.05l.05.95v33q0,4-4,4H814q-4,0-4-4V157l.1-.95m2,.25-.05.2-.05.5v23.9l2.75,2.75L812,186.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2,2h33a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2-2V167.1l-2.4-2.4,2.4-2.4V157l-.05-.7.05.05a1.8,1.8,0,0,0-2-1.35H814q-1.65,0-1.9,1.3" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#b1a077"/>
        <path id="optionBase04" d="M853,190.25V194q0,6-6,6H814q-6,0-6-6v-3.75q.15,5.75,6,5.75h33q5.85,0,6-5.75" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#a3997f"/>
        <path id="wind-solid" d="M1.375,8.25h13.75a4.125,4.125,0,0,0,0-8.25H13.75a1.375,1.375,0,0,0,0,2.75h1.375a1.375,1.375,0,0,1,0,2.75H1.375a1.375,1.375,0,0,0,0,2.75Zm5.5,5.5h-5.5a1.375,1.375,0,1,0,0,2.75h5.5a1.375,1.375,0,0,1,0,2.75H5.5A1.375,1.375,0,0,0,5.5,22H6.875a4.125,4.125,0,0,0,0-8.25Zm11-4.125H1.375a1.375,1.375,0,0,0,0,2.75h16.5a1.375,1.375,0,0,1,0,2.75H16.5a1.375,1.375,0,0,0,0,2.75h1.375a4.125,4.125,0,0,0,0-8.25Z" transform="translate(1441.5 938.167)" fill="#97714a"/>
      </g>
      <g id="optionLayer03" transform="translate(142)">
        <path id="optionInt03" d="M812.1,156.3q.25-1.3,1.9-1.3h33a1.8,1.8,0,0,1,2,1.35l-.05-.05.05.7v5.3l-2.4,2.4,2.4,2.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2,2H814a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2-2v-3.6l2.75-2.75L812,180.9V157l.05-.5.05-.2" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d3bf8f"/>
        <path id="optionOuter03" d="M808,190.25V157q0-6,6-6h33q6,0,6,6v33.25q-.15,5.75-6,5.75H814q-5.85,0-6-5.75m2.1-34.2-.1.95v33q0,4,4,4h33q4,0,4-4V157l-.05-.95Q850.5,153,847,153H814q-3.5,0-3.9,3.05" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d9cdaf"/>
        <path id="optionInner03" d="M810.1,156.05q.4-3.05,3.9-3.05h33q3.5,0,3.95,3.05l.05.95v33q0,4-4,4H814q-4,0-4-4V157l.1-.95m2,.25-.05.2-.05.5v23.9l2.75,2.75L812,186.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2,2h33a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2-2V167.1l-2.4-2.4,2.4-2.4V157l-.05-.7.05.05a1.8,1.8,0,0,0-2-1.35H814q-1.65,0-1.9,1.3" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#b1a077"/>
        <path id="optionBase03" d="M853,190.25V194q0,6-6,6H814q-6,0-6-6v-3.75q.15,5.75,6,5.75h33q5.85,0,6-5.75" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#a3997f"/>
        <path id="feather-pointed-solid" d="M19.191,10.362l-4.975,2.015h4.046a16.584,16.584,0,0,1-1.11,1.848L11.47,16.5h3.674C12.6,18.768,8.963,19.955,3.8,18.773L.876,21.7a1.028,1.028,0,0,1-1.456,0,1.032,1.032,0,0,1,0-1.458L10.289,9.353a.68.68,0,0,0-1.018-.9L2.04,15.7C.21,2.495,14.894.351,19.7.006a1.323,1.323,0,0,1,1.418,1.42A31.442,31.442,0,0,1,19.191,10.362Z" transform="translate(1442.027 938.165)" fill="#97714a"/>
      </g>
      <g id="optionLayer02" transform="translate(71)">
        <path id="optionInt02" d="M812.1,156.3q.25-1.3,1.9-1.3h33a1.8,1.8,0,0,1,2,1.35l-.05-.05.05.7v5.3l-2.4,2.4,2.4,2.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2,2H814a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2-2v-3.6l2.75-2.75L812,180.9V157l.05-.5.05-.2" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d3bf8f"/>
        <path id="optionOuter02" d="M808,190.25V157q0-6,6-6h33q6,0,6,6v33.25q-.15,5.75-6,5.75H814q-5.85,0-6-5.75m2.1-34.2-.1.95v33q0,4,4,4h33q4,0,4-4V157l-.05-.95Q850.5,153,847,153H814q-3.5,0-3.9,3.05" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d9cdaf"/>
        <path id="optionInner02" d="M810.1,156.05q.4-3.05,3.9-3.05h33q3.5,0,3.95,3.05l.05.95v33q0,4-4,4H814q-4,0-4-4V157l.1-.95m2,.25-.05.2-.05.5v23.9l2.75,2.75L812,186.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2,2h33a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2-2V167.1l-2.4-2.4,2.4-2.4V157l-.05-.7.05.05a1.8,1.8,0,0,0-2-1.35H814q-1.65,0-1.9,1.3" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#b1a077"/>
        <path id="optionBase02" d="M853,190.25V194q0,6-6,6H814q-6,0-6-6v-3.75q.15,5.75,6,5.75h33q5.85,0,6-5.75" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#a3997f"/>
        <path id="clock-rotate-left-solid" d="M11,0A11,11,0,1,1,4.714,20.028a1.375,1.375,0,0,1,1.573-2.256A8.25,8.25,0,1,0,11,2.75,8.165,8.165,0,0,0,5.165,5.165L6.488,6.488A1.032,1.032,0,0,1,5.762,8.25H1.031A1.03,1.03,0,0,1,0,7.219V2.49A1.031,1.031,0,0,1,1.76,1.76L3.222,3.222A10.948,10.948,0,0,1,10.961,0Zm0,5.5a1.029,1.029,0,0,1,1.031,1.031v4.043l2.754,2.789a1.006,1.006,0,0,1-1.422,1.422L10.27,11.692a.883.883,0,0,1-.3-.692V6.531A1.029,1.029,0,0,1,11,5.5Z" transform="translate(1441.146 938.167)" fill="#97714a"/>
      </g>
      <g id="optionLayer01">
        <path id="optionInt01" d="M812.1,156.3q.25-1.3,1.9-1.3h33a1.8,1.8,0,0,1,2,1.35l-.05-.05.05.7v5.3l-2.4,2.4,2.4,2.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2,2H814a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2-2v-3.6l2.75-2.75L812,180.9V157l.05-.5.05-.2" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d3bf8f"/>
        <path id="optionOuter01" d="M808,190.25V157q0-6,6-6h33q6,0,6,6v33.25q-.15,5.75-6,5.75H814q-5.85,0-6-5.75m2.1-34.2-.1.95v33q0,4,4,4h33q4,0,4-4V157l-.05-.95Q850.5,153,847,153H814q-3.5,0-3.9,3.05" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d9cdaf"/>
        <path id="optionInner01" d="M810.1,156.05q.4-3.05,3.9-3.05h33q3.5,0,3.95,3.05l.05.95v33q0,4-4,4H814q-4,0-4-4V157l.1-.95m2,.25-.05.2-.05.5v23.9l2.75,2.75L812,186.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2,2h33a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2-2V167.1l-2.4-2.4,2.4-2.4V157l-.05-.7.05.05a1.8,1.8,0,0,0-2-1.35H814q-1.65,0-1.9,1.3" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#b1a077"/>
        <path id="optionBase01" d="M853,190.25V194q0,6-6,6H814q-6,0-6-6v-3.75q.15,5.75,6,5.75h33q5.85,0,6-5.75" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#a3997f"/>
        <path id="signs-post-solid" d="M16.175,1.375A1.419,1.419,0,0,1,17.587,0a1.4,1.4,0,0,1,1.451,1.375h6.767a.718.718,0,0,1,.5.2l2.117,2.063a.678.678,0,0,1,0,.972L26.3,6.673a.718.718,0,0,1-.5.2H9.117A1.419,1.419,0,0,1,7.706,5.5V2.75A1.42,1.42,0,0,1,9.117,1.375ZM27.508,13.75A1.392,1.392,0,0,1,26.1,15.125H9.45a.716.716,0,0,1-.5-.2L6.833,12.861a.674.674,0,0,1,0-.971L8.95,9.827a.757.757,0,0,1,.5-.241h6.726V8.211h2.863V9.586H26.1a1.418,1.418,0,0,1,1.412,1.375ZM17.587,22a1.418,1.418,0,0,1-1.412-1.375V16.5h2.863v4.125A1.4,1.4,0,0,1,17.587,22Z" transform="translate(1434.873 938.167)" fill="#97714a"/>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="btnProfile" transform="translate(0 -9)">
      <g id="Profile">
        <path id="profileOuterRing" d="M258,516.742v-2.465q0-35.743,24.9-61.133l.247-.247q25.39-24.9,61.133-24.9t60.887,24.9v.247q25.39,25.39,25.39,61.133v2.465q-.986,34.264-25.39,58.422-25.144,25.39-60.887,25.39t-61.133-25.39H282.9q-23.911-24.157-24.9-58.422m86.277-79.128q-31.553,0-54.231,22.432-22.432,22.679-22.432,54.231,0,31.8,22.432,54.231,22.432,22.186,54.231,22.186,31.553,0,53.985-22.186l.246-.246q22.185-22.432,22.185-53.985,0-31.8-22.185-54.231-22.432-22.432-54.231-22.432" transform="translate(1447.446 441.8)" fill="#727685"/>
        <path id="profileInnerRing" d="M336.613,429.95q31.8,0,54.231,22.432,22.185,22.432,22.185,54.231,0,31.553-22.185,53.985l-.246.246q-22.432,22.186-53.985,22.186-31.8,0-54.231-22.186-22.432-22.432-22.432-54.231,0-31.553,22.432-54.231,22.679-22.432,54.231-22.432m0,9.86q-27.855,0-47.576,19.227-19.228,19.72-19.227,47.575,0,27.609,19.227,47.082,19.72,19.72,47.576,19.72,27.609,0,47.082-19.72,19.72-19.474,19.721-47.082,0-27.855-19.721-47.575-19.474-19.227-47.082-19.227" transform="translate(1455.11 449.465)" fill="#9b9dad"/>
        <path id="profileIcon" d="M328.753,431.95q27.608,0,47.082,19.227,19.72,19.72,19.72,47.575,0,27.609-19.72,47.082-19.474,19.72-47.082,19.72-27.855,0-47.576-19.72-19.228-19.474-19.227-47.082,0-27.855,19.227-47.575,19.72-19.227,47.576-19.227" transform="translate(1462.969 457.323)" fill="#838796"/>
      </g>
      <g id="DBConnected" transform="translate(74 62)">
        <g id="Group_426" data-name="Group 426" transform="translate(13993 8796)">
          <path id="Path_234" data-name="Path 234" d="M386.5,434.5a15.525,15.525,0,1,0-.05,22l.05-.05a15.633,15.633,0,0,0,0-21.95M358,446v-.5a17.072,17.072,0,0,1,5.05-12.4l.05-.05a17.687,17.687,0,0,1,24.75,0v.05A16.9,16.9,0,0,1,393,445.5v.5a17.506,17.506,0,0,1-29.9,11.85h-.05A16.962,16.962,0,0,1,358,446" transform="translate(-12586 -8285)" fill="#d9cdaf"/>
          <path id="Path_235" data-name="Path 235" d="M386.5,434.5a15.633,15.633,0,0,1,0,21.95l-.05.05a15.525,15.525,0,1,1,.05-22m-1.45,1.35a13.1,13.1,0,0,0-9.55-3.9,13.322,13.322,0,0,0-13.55,13.55,13.486,13.486,0,0,0,13.55,13.55,13.658,13.658,0,0,0,13.55-13.55,13.151,13.151,0,0,0-4-9.65" transform="translate(-12586 -8285)" fill="#b1a077"/>
          <path id="Path_236" data-name="Path 236" d="M385.05,435.85a13.151,13.151,0,0,1,4,9.65,13.658,13.658,0,0,1-13.55,13.55,13.486,13.486,0,0,1-13.55-13.55,13.322,13.322,0,0,1,13.55-13.55,13.1,13.1,0,0,1,9.55,3.9" transform="translate(-12586 -8285)" fill="#d3bf8f"/>
        </g>
        <path id="plug-circle-check-solid" d="M3.282,0A1.094,1.094,0,0,1,4.376,1.094V4.376H2.188V1.094A1.094,1.094,0,0,1,3.282,0ZM9.846,0A1.094,1.094,0,0,1,10.94,1.094V4.376H8.752V1.094A1.094,1.094,0,0,1,9.846,0Zm2.188,5.47a1.093,1.093,0,0,1,1.094,1.094A1.307,1.307,0,0,1,13.1,6.8a6,6,0,0,0-4.352,5.785,6.24,6.24,0,0,0,.106,1.138,5.425,5.425,0,0,1-1.2.393V17.5H5.47V14.113A5.5,5.5,0,0,1,1.094,8.752V7.658a1.094,1.094,0,0,1,0-2.188Zm7.658,7.111A4.923,4.923,0,1,1,14.77,7.658,4.924,4.924,0,0,1,19.693,12.582ZM16.3,11.1l-2.075,2.075-.981-.981a.546.546,0,0,0-.773.773l1.368,1.368a.543.543,0,0,0,.773,0l2.462-2.462A.546.546,0,0,0,16.3,11.1Z" transform="translate(1772.654 947.747)" fill="#97714a"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I've managed to start by creating the svg object and applying the defs and filters, I'm just having trouble with applying the `<g>` and `<path>` tags.

```html
// create a svg element
const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 482.026 172.554");
svg.setAttribute("width", "482.026");
svg.setAttribute("height", "172.554");
svg.setAttribute("id", "svg");
svg.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
svg.setAttribute("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");

// create a defs element
const defs = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "defs");
// create a filter element
const filterOuter = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "filter"
);
filterOuter.setAttribute("id", "layerOuter");
filterOuter.setAttribute("x", "0");
filterOuter.setAttribute("y", "35.6");
filterOuter.setAttribute("width", "364.473");
filterOuter.setAttribute("height", "100.059");
filterOuter.setAttribute("filterUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
// create a feOffset element
const feOffsetOuter = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "feOffset"
);
feOffsetOuter.setAttribute("dy", "3");
feOffsetOuter.setAttribute("input", "SourceAlpha");
// create a feGaussianBlur element
const feGaussianBlurOuter = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "feGaussianBlur"
);
feGaussianBlurOuter.setAttribute("stdDeviation", "3");
feGaussianBlurOuter.setAttribute("result", "blur");
// create a feFlood element
const feFloodOuter = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "feFlood"
);
feFloodOuter.setAttribute("flood-opacity", "0.459");
// create a feComposite element
const feCompositeOuter = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "feComposite"
);
feCompositeOuter.setAttribute("operator", "in");
feCompositeOuter.setAttribute("in2", "blur");
// create a feComposite element
const feCompositeOuter2 = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "feComposite"
);
feCompositeOuter2.setAttribute("in", "SourceGraphic");
// create a filter element
const filterBase = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "filter"
);
filterBase.setAttribute("id", "layerBase");
filterBase.setAttribute("x", "0");
filterBase.setAttribute("y", "107.175");
filterBase.setAttribute("width", "364.473");
filterBase.setAttribute("height", "35.78");
filterBase.setAttribute("filterUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
// create a feOffset element
const feOffsetBase = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "feOffset"
);
feOffsetBase.setAttribute("dy", "3");
feOffsetBase.setAttribute("input", "SourceAlpha");
// create a feGaussianBlur element
const feGaussianBlurBase = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "feGaussianBlur"
);
feGaussianBlurBase.setAttribute("stdDeviation", "3");
feGaussianBlurBase.setAttribute("result", "blur-2");
// create a feFlood element
const feFloodBase = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "feFlood"
);
feFloodBase.setAttribute("flood-opacity", "0.431");
// create a feComposite element
const feCompositeBase = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "feComposite"
);
feCompositeBase.setAttribute("operator", "in");
feCompositeBase.setAttribute("in2", "blur-2");
// create a feComposite element
const feCompositeBase2 = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "feComposite"
);
feCompositeBase2.setAttribute("in", "SourceGraphic");

// append the elements to the defs element
filterOuter.appendChild(feOffsetOuter);
filterOuter.appendChild(feGaussianBlurOuter);
filterOuter.appendChild(feFloodOuter);
filterOuter.appendChild(feCompositeOuter);
filterOuter.appendChild(feCompositeOuter2);
filterBase.appendChild(feOffsetBase);
filterBase.appendChild(feGaussianBlurBase);
filterBase.appendChild(feFloodBase);
filterBase.appendChild(feCompositeBase);
filterBase.appendChild(feCompositeBase2);
defs.appendChild(filterOuter);
defs.appendChild(filterBase);
svg.appendChild(defs);
```

Comment: so, you want to convert from SVG to javascript in the browser? oh, you're just doing it by hand ... right ... why not just copy the SVG to **your** server, then it won't be "external"

Comment: No not in the browser I'm building an interface in javascript using the converted svg code

Comment: Due to the way the project is being setup I dont edit the index.html and apply all code to the body of the index page through javascript code.

Comment: so, you can't `fetch` the svg?

Comment: I dont believe fetch will allow manipulation.
The aim is to manipulate the vector graphic while the session is running and svgs are very temperamental and wont allow any manipulation if the svg code is external to the index page.

Comment: what do you mean by "external" ... do you mean not "inline" or do you mean cross origin?

Comment: External as in a sperate file?

Comment: well, you can load it using fetch, then parse it using `new DOMParser().parseFromString` using `'image/svg+xml'` as the `type` - then you have full access to manipulate what you want

Comment: Awsome, I'll give this a try

Comment: Take inspiration from [the ``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the SVG is not "cross origin" ... or, if it is, the server allows you to read it (CORS) ... then you can do something like this

```
const resp = await fetch("./image.svg");
const text = await resp.text();
const dp = new DOMParser();
const svg = dp.parseFromString(text, 'image/svg+xml');
const root = svg.documentElement;
// you can manipulate whatever you like here
root.querySelectorAll('[fill="#838796"]').forEach(e => e.setAttribute('fill', 'green'));
// done this way, you can manipulate after adding to the DOM too
document.body.appendChild(root);
root.querySelectorAll('[fill="#b1a077"]').forEach(e => e.setAttribute('fill', 'red'));
```

Comment: These two examples by yourself and IT Goldman do work in some frameworks I've tested them on so they are valid however due to WebPack being a tag restrictive on loaders and other things I do believe that I'll need another method other than fetching.

Creating the SVG in JS is where I'm hoping to go.

Comment: I must misunderstand the objective then - can't see how webpack can affect this code at all

Answer (score 1):

I had to set up an example from @Jaromanda X code

```js
var fetched_svg = document.getElementById("source").innerHTML;
const text = fetched_svg;
const dp = new DOMParser();
const svg = dp.parseFromString(text, 'image/svg+xml');
const root = svg.documentElement;
// you can manipulate whatever you like here
root.querySelectorAll('[fill="#838796"]').forEach(e => e.setAttribute('fill', 'green'));
// done this way, you can manipulate after adding to the DOM too
document.body.appendChild(root);
root.querySelectorAll('[fill="#b1a077"]').forEach(e => e.setAttribute('fill', 'red'));
```

```html
<div id="source" style="display:none"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="482.026" height="172.554" viewBox="0 0 482.026 172.554"> <defs> <filter id="layerOuter" x="0" y="35.6" width="364.473" height="100.059" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> <feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/> <feFlood flood-opacity="0.459"/> <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur"/> <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/> </filter> <filter id="layerBase" x="0" y="107.175" width="364.473" height="35.78" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> <feOffset dy="3" input="SourceAlpha"/> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" result="blur-2"/> <feFlood flood-opacity="0.431"/> <feComposite operator="in" in2="blur-2"/> <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/> </filter> </defs> <g id="frmMenu" transform="translate(-1395.974 -860.8)"> <g id="btnGroupLayers" transform="translate(0 -9)"> <g id="LayerBar"> <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1395.97, 869.8)" filter="url(#layerOuter)"> <path id="layerOuter-2" data-name="layerOuter" d="M730.735,40.209q-.821-5.562-7.2-5.562H398.941q-6.382,0-7.112,5.562l-.182,1.732v60.177q0,7.294,7.294,7.294h324.59q7.294,0,7.294-7.294V41.941l-.091-1.732M388,102.574V41.941Q388,31,398.941,31h324.59q10.941,0,10.941,10.941v60.633q-.273,10.485-10.941,10.485H398.941q-10.668,0-10.941-10.485" transform="translate(-379 10.6)" fill="#9b9dad"/> </g> <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1395.97, 869.8)" filter="url(#layerBase)"> <path id="layerBase-2" data-name="layerBase" d="M734.473,70.25v6.838q0,10.941-10.941,10.941H398.941Q388,88.03,388,77.088V70.25q.274,10.485,10.941,10.485h324.59q10.668,0,10.941-10.485" transform="translate(-379 42.92)" fill="#616374"/> </g> <path id="layerMid" d="M729.088,38.562l.091,1.732v60.177q0,7.294-7.294,7.294H397.294q-7.294,0-7.294-7.294V40.294l.182-1.732Q390.912,33,397.294,33h324.59q6.382,0,7.2,5.562m-3.556,1.732-.091-1.276.091.091q-.638-2.462-3.647-2.462H463.853l-5.106,5.106-5.106-5.106h-17.05l-4.1,4.1-4.1-4.1H397.294q-3.009,0-3.465,2.371l-.091.365-.091.912V83.877l5.015,5.015-5.015,5.015v6.565q0,3.647,3.647,3.647H564.878l5.015-5.015,5.015,5.015H652.5l2.827-2.826,2.826,2.826h63.733q3.647,0,3.647-3.647V58.712l-4.377-4.376,4.377-4.377V40.294" transform="translate(1018.621 882.048)" fill="#727685"/> <path id="layerInner" d="M723.885,38.647v9.665l-4.377,4.377,4.377,4.376V98.824q0,3.647-3.647,3.647H656.5l-2.826-2.826-2.826,2.826H573.26l-5.015-5.015-5.015,5.015H395.647q-3.647,0-3.647-3.647V92.259l5.015-5.015L392,82.23V38.647l.091-.912.091-.365Q392.638,35,395.647,35h31.091l4.1,4.1,4.1-4.1h17.05l5.106,5.106L462.206,35H720.237q3.009,0,3.647,2.462l-.091-.091.091,1.276" transform="translate(1020.268 883.694)" fill="#838796"/> </g> <g id="optionLayer04" transform="translate(213)"> <path id="optionInt04" d="M812.1,156.3q.25-1.3,1.9-1.3h33a1.8,1.8,0,0,1,2,1.35l-.05-.05.05.7v5.3l-2.4,2.4,2.4,2.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2,2H814a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2-2v-3.6l2.75-2.75L812,180.9V157l.05-.5.05-.2" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d3bf8f"/> <path id="optionOuter04" d="M808,190.25V157q0-6,6-6h33q6,0,6,6v33.25q-.15,5.75-6,5.75H814q-5.85,0-6-5.75m2.1-34.2-.1.95v33q0,4,4,4h33q4,0,4-4V157l-.05-.95Q850.5,153,847,153H814q-3.5,0-3.9,3.05" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d9cdaf"/> <path id="optionInner04" d="M810.1,156.05q.4-3.05,3.9-3.05h33q3.5,0,3.95,3.05l.05.95v33q0,4-4,4H814q-4,0-4-4V157l.1-.95m2,.25-.05.2-.05.5v23.9l2.75,2.75L812,186.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2,2h33a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2-2V167.1l-2.4-2.4,2.4-2.4V157l-.05-.7.05.05a1.8,1.8,0,0,0-2-1.35H814q-1.65,0-1.9,1.3" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#b1a077"/> <path id="optionBase04" d="M853,190.25V194q0,6-6,6H814q-6,0-6-6v-3.75q.15,5.75,6,5.75h33q5.85,0,6-5.75" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#a3997f"/> <path id="wind-solid" d="M1.375,8.25h13.75a4.125,4.125,0,0,0,0-8.25H13.75a1.375,1.375,0,0,0,0,2.75h1.375a1.375,1.375,0,0,1,0,2.75H1.375a1.375,1.375,0,0,0,0,2.75Zm5.5,5.5h-5.5a1.375,1.375,0,1,0,0,2.75h5.5a1.375,1.375,0,0,1,0,2.75H5.5A1.375,1.375,0,0,0,5.5,22H6.875a4.125,4.125,0,0,0,0-8.25Zm11-4.125H1.375a1.375,1.375,0,0,0,0,2.75h16.5a1.375,1.375,0,0,1,0,2.75H16.5a1.375,1.375,0,0,0,0,2.75h1.375a4.125,4.125,0,0,0,0-8.25Z" transform="translate(1441.5 938.167)" fill="#97714a"/> </g> <g id="optionLayer03" transform="translate(142)"> <path id="optionInt03" d="M812.1,156.3q.25-1.3,1.9-1.3h33a1.8,1.8,0,0,1,2,1.35l-.05-.05.05.7v5.3l-2.4,2.4,2.4,2.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2,2H814a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2-2v-3.6l2.75-2.75L812,180.9V157l.05-.5.05-.2" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d3bf8f"/> <path id="optionOuter03" d="M808,190.25V157q0-6,6-6h33q6,0,6,6v33.25q-.15,5.75-6,5.75H814q-5.85,0-6-5.75m2.1-34.2-.1.95v33q0,4,4,4h33q4,0,4-4V157l-.05-.95Q850.5,153,847,153H814q-3.5,0-3.9,3.05" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d9cdaf"/> <path id="optionInner03" d="M810.1,156.05q.4-3.05,3.9-3.05h33q3.5,0,3.95,3.05l.05.95v33q0,4-4,4H814q-4,0-4-4V157l.1-.95m2,.25-.05.2-.05.5v23.9l2.75,2.75L812,186.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2,2h33a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2-2V167.1l-2.4-2.4,2.4-2.4V157l-.05-.7.05.05a1.8,1.8,0,0,0-2-1.35H814q-1.65,0-1.9,1.3" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#b1a077"/> <path id="optionBase03" d="M853,190.25V194q0,6-6,6H814q-6,0-6-6v-3.75q.15,5.75,6,5.75h33q5.85,0,6-5.75" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#a3997f"/> <path id="feather-pointed-solid" d="M19.191,10.362l-4.975,2.015h4.046a16.584,16.584,0,0,1-1.11,1.848L11.47,16.5h3.674C12.6,18.768,8.963,19.955,3.8,18.773L.876,21.7a1.028,1.028,0,0,1-1.456,0,1.032,1.032,0,0,1,0-1.458L10.289,9.353a.68.68,0,0,0-1.018-.9L2.04,15.7C.21,2.495,14.894.351,19.7.006a1.323,1.323,0,0,1,1.418,1.42A31.442,31.442,0,0,1,19.191,10.362Z" transform="translate(1442.027 938.165)" fill="#97714a"/> </g> <g id="optionLayer02" transform="translate(71)"> <path id="optionInt02" d="M812.1,156.3q.25-1.3,1.9-1.3h33a1.8,1.8,0,0,1,2,1.35l-.05-.05.05.7v5.3l-2.4,2.4,2.4,2.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2,2H814a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2-2v-3.6l2.75-2.75L812,180.9V157l.05-.5.05-.2" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d3bf8f"/> <path id="optionOuter02" d="M808,190.25V157q0-6,6-6h33q6,0,6,6v33.25q-.15,5.75-6,5.75H814q-5.85,0-6-5.75m2.1-34.2-.1.95v33q0,4,4,4h33q4,0,4-4V157l-.05-.95Q850.5,153,847,153H814q-3.5,0-3.9,3.05" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d9cdaf"/> <path id="optionInner02" d="M810.1,156.05q.4-3.05,3.9-3.05h33q3.5,0,3.95,3.05l.05.95v33q0,4-4,4H814q-4,0-4-4V157l.1-.95m2,.25-.05.2-.05.5v23.9l2.75,2.75L812,186.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2,2h33a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2-2V167.1l-2.4-2.4,2.4-2.4V157l-.05-.7.05.05a1.8,1.8,0,0,0-2-1.35H814q-1.65,0-1.9,1.3" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#b1a077"/> <path id="optionBase02" d="M853,190.25V194q0,6-6,6H814q-6,0-6-6v-3.75q.15,5.75,6,5.75h33q5.85,0,6-5.75" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#a3997f"/> <path id="clock-rotate-left-solid" d="M11,0A11,11,0,1,1,4.714,20.028a1.375,1.375,0,0,1,1.573-2.256A8.25,8.25,0,1,0,11,2.75,8.165,8.165,0,0,0,5.165,5.165L6.488,6.488A1.032,1.032,0,0,1,5.762,8.25H1.031A1.03,1.03,0,0,1,0,7.219V2.49A1.031,1.031,0,0,1,1.76,1.76L3.222,3.222A10.948,10.948,0,0,1,10.961,0Zm0,5.5a1.029,1.029,0,0,1,1.031,1.031v4.043l2.754,2.789a1.006,1.006,0,0,1-1.422,1.422L10.27,11.692a.883.883,0,0,1-.3-.692V6.531A1.029,1.029,0,0,1,11,5.5Z" transform="translate(1441.146 938.167)" fill="#97714a"/> </g> <g id="optionLayer01"> <path id="optionInt01" d="M812.1,156.3q.25-1.3,1.9-1.3h33a1.8,1.8,0,0,1,2,1.35l-.05-.05.05.7v5.3l-2.4,2.4,2.4,2.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2,2H814a1.768,1.768,0,0,1-2-2v-3.6l2.75-2.75L812,180.9V157l.05-.5.05-.2" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d3bf8f"/> <path id="optionOuter01" d="M808,190.25V157q0-6,6-6h33q6,0,6,6v33.25q-.15,5.75-6,5.75H814q-5.85,0-6-5.75m2.1-34.2-.1.95v33q0,4,4,4h33q4,0,4-4V157l-.05-.95Q850.5,153,847,153H814q-3.5,0-3.9,3.05" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#d9cdaf"/> <path id="optionInner01" d="M810.1,156.05q.4-3.05,3.9-3.05h33q3.5,0,3.95,3.05l.05.95v33q0,4-4,4H814q-4,0-4-4V157l.1-.95m2,.25-.05.2-.05.5v23.9l2.75,2.75L812,186.4V190a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2,2h33a1.768,1.768,0,0,0,2-2V167.1l-2.4-2.4,2.4-2.4V157l-.05-.7.05.05a1.8,1.8,0,0,0-2-1.35H814q-1.65,0-1.9,1.3" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#b1a077"/> <path id="optionBase01" d="M853,190.25V194q0,6-6,6H814q-6,0-6-6v-3.75q.15,5.75,6,5.75h33q5.85,0,6-5.75" transform="translate(622 776)" fill="#a3997f"/> <path id="signs-post-solid" d="M16.175,1.375A1.419,1.419,0,0,1,17.587,0a1.4,1.4,0,0,1,1.451,1.375h6.767a.718.718,0,0,1,.5.2l2.117,2.063a.678.678,0,0,1,0,.972L26.3,6.673a.718.718,0,0,1-.5.2H9.117A1.419,1.419,0,0,1,7.706,5.5V2.75A1.42,1.42,0,0,1,9.117,1.375ZM27.508,13.75A1.392,1.392,0,0,1,26.1,15.125H9.45a.716.716,0,0,1-.5-.2L6.833,12.861a.674.674,0,0,1,0-.971L8.95,9.827a.757.757,0,0,1,.5-.241h6.726V8.211h2.863V9.586H26.1a1.418,1.418,0,0,1,1.412,1.375ZM17.587,22a1.418,1.418,0,0,1-1.412-1.375V16.5h2.863v4.125A1.4,1.4,0,0,1,17.587,22Z" transform="translate(1434.873 938.167)" fill="#97714a"/> </g> </g> <g id="btnProfile" transform="translate(0 -9)"> <g id="Profile"> <path id="profileOuterRing" d="M258,516.742v-2.465q0-35.743,24.9-61.133l.247-.247q25.39-24.9,61.133-24.9t60.887,24.9v.247q25.39,25.39,25.39,61.133v2.465q-.986,34.264-25.39,58.422-25.144,25.39-60.887,25.39t-61.133-25.39H282.9q-23.911-24.157-24.9-58.422m86.277-79.128q-31.553,0-54.231,22.432-22.432,22.679-22.432,54.231,0,31.8,22.432,54.231,22.432,22.186,54.231,22.186,31.553,0,53.985-22.186l.246-.246q22.185-22.432,22.185-53.985,0-31.8-22.185-54.231-22.432-22.432-54.231-22.432" transform="translate(1447.446 441.8)" fill="#727685"/> <path id="profileInnerRing" d="M336.613,429.95q31.8,0,54.231,22.432,22.185,22.432,22.185,54.231,0,31.553-22.185,53.985l-.246.246q-22.432,22.186-53.985,22.186-31.8,0-54.231-22.186-22.432-22.432-22.432-54.231,0-31.553,22.432-54.231,22.679-22.432,54.231-22.432m0,9.86q-27.855,0-47.576,19.227-19.228,19.72-19.227,47.575,0,27.609,19.227,47.082,19.72,19.72,47.576,19.72,27.609,0,47.082-19.72,19.72-19.474,19.721-47.082,0-27.855-19.721-47.575-19.474-19.227-47.082-19.227" transform="translate(1455.11 449.465)" fill="#9b9dad"/> <path id="profileIcon" d="M328.753,431.95q27.608,0,47.082,19.227,19.72,19.72,19.72,47.575,0,27.609-19.72,47.082-19.474,19.72-47.082,19.72-27.855,0-47.576-19.72-19.228-19.474-19.227-47.082,0-27.855,19.227-47.575,19.72-19.227,47.576-19.227" transform="translate(1462.969 457.323)" fill="#838796"/> </g> <g id="DBConnected" transform="translate(74 62)"> <g id="Group_426" data-name="Group 426" transform="translate(13993 8796)"> <path id="Path_234" data-name="Path 234" d="M386.5,434.5a15.525,15.525,0,1,0-.05,22l.05-.05a15.633,15.633,0,0,0,0-21.95M358,446v-.5a17.072,17.072,0,0,1,5.05-12.4l.05-.05a17.687,17.687,0,0,1,24.75,0v.05A16.9,16.9,0,0,1,393,445.5v.5a17.506,17.506,0,0,1-29.9,11.85h-.05A16.962,16.962,0,0,1,358,446" transform="translate(-12586 -8285)" fill="#d9cdaf"/> <path id="Path_235" data-name="Path 235" d="M386.5,434.5a15.633,15.633,0,0,1,0,21.95l-.05.05a15.525,15.525,0,1,1,.05-22m-1.45,1.35a13.1,13.1,0,0,0-9.55-3.9,13.322,13.322,0,0,0-13.55,13.55,13.486,13.486,0,0,0,13.55,13.55,13.658,13.658,0,0,0,13.55-13.55,13.151,13.151,0,0,0-4-9.65" transform="translate(-12586 -8285)" fill="#b1a077"/> <path id="Path_236" data-name="Path 236" d="M385.05,435.85a13.151,13.151,0,0,1,4,9.65,13.658,13.658,0,0,1-13.55,13.55,13.486,13.486,0,0,1-13.55-13.55,13.322,13.322,0,0,1,13.55-13.55,13.1,13.1,0,0,1,9.55,3.9" transform="translate(-12586 -8285)" fill="#d3bf8f"/> </g> <path id="plug-circle-check-solid" d="M3.282,0A1.094,1.094,0,0,1,4.376,1.094V4.376H2.188V1.094A1.094,1.094,0,0,1,3.282,0ZM9.846,0A1.094,1.094,0,0,1,10.94,1.094V4.376H8.752V1.094A1.094,1.094,0,0,1,9.846,0Zm2.188,5.47a1.093,1.093,0,0,1,1.094,1.094A1.307,1.307,0,0,1,13.1,6.8a6,6,0,0,0-4.352,5.785,6.24,6.24,0,0,0,.106,1.138,5.425,5.425,0,0,1-1.2.393V17.5H5.47V14.113A5.5,5.5,0,0,1,1.094,8.752V7.658a1.094,1.094,0,0,1,0-2.188Zm7.658,7.111A4.923,4.923,0,1,1,14.77,7.658,4.924,4.924,0,0,1,19.693,12.582ZM16.3,11.1l-2.075,2.075-.981-.981a.546.546,0,0,0-.773.773l1.368,1.368a.543.543,0,0,0,.773,0l2.462-2.462A.546.546,0,0,0,16.3,11.1Z" transform="translate(1772.654 947.747)" fill="#97714a"/> </g> </g> </g></svg></div>
```